# Does a TFS 2010 backup require the server to be offline?

Tags: tfs, tfs-2010

I have been told that our TFS 2010 server must be taken offline during the backup process, which means that there is a chunk of time every night where the server is unavailable.

I have searched through the TFS documentation, and writeup of using TFS Power Tools for backup (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb552295.aspx and http://blogs.msdn.com/b/bharry/archive/2010/08/18/backing-up-and-restoring-your-tfs-server.aspx), and have been unable to find anything that indicates either way.

Is it possible to keep the TFS 2010 server online during a backup, or must it be taken offline?

Comment: Yes, you can keep your TFS server(s) on-line during backup.  The tricky part is keeping the data synchronized.  If you utilize the TFS Power Tools (as you hinted at above) then this will be taken care of for you.